# Laravel 4.2 session::get() method not returning session data in controllers

Tags: php, session, laravel

Hi help me,

login code

```
         public function store()
          {
             $credentials = array(
            'u_email' =>  Input::get('email'),
            'password' =>  Input::get('password'));


           if (Auth::attempt($credentials) ) {

            $user = Auth::user()->toArray();
            $userrole = with(new User)->get_user_role($user['u_id']);

            $userobj['u_id']        =   $user['u_id'];
            $userobj['u_shortcode'] =   $user['u_shortcode'];
            $userobj['utype']       =   $user['utype'];
            $userobj['u_title']     =   $user['u_title'];
            $userobj['u_fname']     =   $user['u_fname'];
            $userobj['u_lname']     =   $user['u_lname'];
            $userobj['u_email']     =   $user['u_email'];
            $userobj['u_role']      =   $userrole;
            $userobj['id']          =   Session::getId();

            Session::put('admin', $userobj);
            $value = Session::get('admin');


            return Response::json([
                    'user' => $userobj ],
                202
            );

        }else{
            return Response::json([
                    'flash2' => 'Authentication failed'],
                202
            );
        }
}
```

and my second controller is:

```
       public function get_sessionobj()
       {

        var_dump(Session::all());
        $value = Session::get('admin');
        print_r($value);
        exit();
      }
```

when i am calling second controller after login then session data not printed. in login controller Session::get('admin') function returning data. and i am using file driver for session storage. I have seen my session file there was some data like this:

```
   a:5:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"XrUgs7QLPlXvjvyzFaTdmDpqGL0aSZRzkJS0il9f";s:38:"login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc";s:1:"1";s:5:"admin";a:9:{s:4:"u_id";s:1:"1";s:11:"u_shortcode";s:5:"u1001";s:5:"utype";s:1:"1";s:7:"u_title";s:3:"Mr.";s:7:"u_fname";s:6:"Aristo";s:7:"u_lname";s:5:"Singh";s:7:"u_email";s:24:"chandan.singh@jetwave.in";s:6:"u_role";a:3:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";i:2;s:1:"3";}s:2:"id";s:40:"cd074f7f61fcc88b3d92c482e57e8a12dc888958";}s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1410525787;s:1:"c";i:1410525787;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with that. How/when are you calling the second method 'get_sessionobj' ?

Comment: I am calling with another route AuthenticationController@get_sessionobj (in same browser where i have called login)

Comment: after calling this returning result only array(1) { '_token' => string(40) " some token "}

Comment: also i am using angularjs and i have made customhasherserviceprovide

Comment: Looks like there's a problem with the request. Without seeing the Angular code it's difficult to say

Comment: Thanks RobbieP for giving attention, I have sort out this problem.  actually i have created custom CustomHasherServiceProvider that conflict  with session library. Any way really thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call a function `get_sessionobj()` in store function

Example:

```
public function store(){
  $this->get_sessionobj();
}
```